# Events in Google calendar

Tags: android, events, google-calendar-api

I am using Google calendar to save the event using my application. Is it possible to get the created event details to my application? If possible, How can we achieve it?

Comment: `CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI` its an uri for google calendar events table. Now you can use `ContentResolver` to insert or read data to/from the this table. It's just like reading data with your custom database (using `Cursor`). You can read more in developers documentation.

Comment: Yes. You can get started by reading [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/android) and the [Calendar API guide](https://developers.google.com/calendar/overview).

Answer (score 0):

**DTSTART**

added in API level 14

```
String DTSTART
```

The time the event starts in UTC millis since epoch. Column name.

Type: `INTEGER (long; millis since epoch)`

Constant Value: `dtstart`

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#DTSTART)

Comment: Please do not push users into accepting your answers.

Comment: But they can usually better estimate who helped them and who did not. Also, I did not downvote you if that’s what you meant.

Comment: I agree , that's why I tell them to reward those who helped them,even me. some users don't know that and some reward others and say thank you for letting me know.a good accepting rate gets help quicker